# ArrayList troubles

Tags: java, arraylist

I was wondering how to reference an ArrayList a different method than it was declared in.
For example I am writing a program that allows me to create a playlist of songs, so in one method I have createAPlaylist and then another method I have shuffle().
In my playlist method I have created an ArrayList but I am having trouble using this arrayList in my shuffle method. There is some code below for context:

```
public static void createAPlaylist() {
        try {
            System.out.println("We have the following tracks:");
            ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
            String firstSong = jukebox.allTracks.get(0).getTitle();
            songs.add(firstSong);

            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
                System.out.println(SPACES + (index + 1) + ". " + jukebox.allTracks.get(index).getTitle());
            }

            System.out.println("Select a track to add to the playlist: ");
            int songNumber = input.nextInt();
            String songSelected = songs.get(songNumber);
            songs.add(songSelected);
            input.nextLine();
            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\nplease select a valid song number.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't catch exceptions like this. You are catching *all* exceptions, including `RuntimeException`s, like `NullPointerException`s, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s and `NoSuchElementException`s. That means that you are hiding the cause of the exception, by simply printing "please select a valid song number". This'll make errors in your code harder to debug.

Comment: Ideally, you should make `createAPlaylist()` function to return List of objects, then pass it to `shuffle(List<Song> musicList)` function.

Comment: You want to learn what "scope" is about. Variables are only visible in the scope they are defined in. You **declare** the list inside the try block, thus it is only visible/known in that block. That simple.

Answer (score 1):

This is what method parameters are for:

```
public static void createAPlaylist() {
    ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<>();
    shuffle(songs);
}

public static void shuffle(ArrayList<String> songs) {
    // Do stuff with your ArrayList here
}
```

Comment: For the record: `static`  can be omitted since we don't know weather Author implements in Main.java file.

Comment: Bad advise. When that method "ends", the playlist ist still "gone". You only solved half of the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can the arraylist from the `createAPlaylist` method and pass that to `shuffle` method:

Like:

```
 public static List<String> createAPlaylist() {
  ...
  ...
  ... 
  return songs;
 }

/// and then in shuffle method receive that as parameter :

public static void shuffle(List<String> songs){
    // access that songs list by
}
```

Or you could:

Instead of method variable declare that arraylist as class variable..

Like:

```
public class ClassName{
 public static ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
 
 public static void createAPlaylist() {
  ...
  ...
  ... 
  // reset the songs.
  songs = new ArrayList<String>();
  ...
 }

/// and then in another method:

public static void suffle(){
    // access that songs list by
   List<String> createdSongs = ClassName.songs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, variables are only available within the context they are created -  so if you create an `ArrayList` inside a method, you cannot access it outside of that method unless you store it in the method’s class, or you return the variable from the method it’s made it.

You can either declare the `ArrayList` outside of the method, as a class field, like so:

```
public class Foo {

    private static ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void createAPlaylist() {
        arrayList.add();

        etc...
    }
}
```

Or you could return the `ArrayList` from the method like so:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = createAPlaylist();
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> createAPlaylist() {

    ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Your code here

    // Note that you have to return the list from 
    // inside the catch block!


    // I’d recommend creating the ‘songs’ ArrayList 
    // outside of the ‘try’ block, so that you can 
    // have a fallback if something fails in the ‘try’

    return songs;
    }
}
```

I don’t know if you intend to have this all static. I’d think it will work better as non static, but that’s a matter for another question, so I’ve left it as-is in the examples.

Sorry if this isn’t formatted perfectly - I’m on a mobile device and don’t have my IDE.